# Double Dropdown List in Plotly

Tags: python, callback, plotly, visualization, plotly-dash

I want to create a double dropdown list in plotly. I should be able to select the year and the condition of the forecast.

Here are the data sets: [Collisions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zull4WIGUWThWyc526n4nno6FTjaag61/view?usp=sharing) and [Forecast](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GvwNbo_BIiceou3becvbRtcGWB9V99Oo/view?usp=sharing)

My datasets are look like this:
1st: Collisions
[Collisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTnYJ.png)
Where I have from 2013 to 2022 grouped by Year, Month and Day
and then Forecast
[Forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MmpP.png)

I have been able to do it with one year, but I am not able to do it with 2 dropdwon list, I cannot understand the logic behind why my code doesn't work.

Basically I want to add another dropdown list where I could select the year.

Here is my code that creates one working dropdown list:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=6, cols=2, specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                            [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                             [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                              [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                               [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                                [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                            ])

# condition = "snow"
colors = {"Collisions": "#FFA07A",
          "tempmax": "#FF0000",
          "tempmin": "#00FF00",
          "temp": "#7EC0EE",
          "humidity": "#808080",
          "precip": "#FFC0CB",
          "snow": "#800080",
          "visibility": "#FFA500",
          }


forecast = list(df_brook_fore.columns[1:])
months = list(range(1,13))

for i, mon in enumerate(months):
    for j, condition in enumerate(forecast):
        column_idx  = 1 if i%2==0 else 2
        row_idx = i//2+1

        days = list(range(1, len(df_brook_fil_group[1]) + 1))
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=days, y=df_brook_fil_group[mon], marker_color=colors["Collisions"], visible=(j == 0),
                            name='Collisions' if i == 0 else '', showlegend=True if i == 0 else False),
                            row=row_idx, col=column_idx)
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=days, y=df_brook_fore[condition][mon], visible=(j == 0),
                                marker_color=colors[condition], name=condition if i == 0 else '',
                                showlegend=True if i == 0 else False), row=row_idx, col=column_idx, secondary_y=True)

        fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Collisions", row=row_idx, col=column_idx, secondary_y=False, showgrid=False)
        fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Visibility", row=row_idx, col=column_idx, secondary_y=True, showgrid=False)

fig.update_layout(width=1000, height=1200, coloraxis=dict(colorscale='Bluered_r'), showlegend=True)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label=condition, method="update", args=[{"visible": [((j == i*2) or (j == i*2+1)) for j in range(
                    len(forecast)*2)]}, {"title": "Normalized Collision Count by Hour for " + condition}])
                for i, condition in enumerate(forecast)
            ]),
            x=0.05, y=1.1, xanchor="left", yanchor="top"
        )
    ],
    title_text="Normalized Collision Count by Hour for " + forecast[0],
    title_x=0.5
)

fig.show()
```

And here is my attempted code to create 2 dropdown lists. I am quite sure that the problem is in the visible option from the dropdown button, but I do not now how to fix it.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=6, cols=2, specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                            [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                             [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                              [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                               [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                                [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                            ])

# condition = "snow"
colors = {"Collisions": "#FFA07A",
          "tempmax": "#FF0000",
          "tempmin": "#00FF00",
          "temp": "#7EC0EE",
          "humidity": "#808080",
          "precip": "#FFC0CB",
          "snow": "#800080",
          "visibility": "#FFA500",
          }


forecast = list(df_brook_fore.columns[1:])
months = list(range(1,13))
years = list(df_brook_fore.index.get_level_values(0).unique())

for i, mon in enumerate(months):
    for k, year in enumerate(years):
        
        for j, condition in enumerate(forecast):
            column_idx  = 1 if i%2==0 else 2
            row_idx = i//2+1

            days = list(range(1, len(df_brook_fil_group[year][mon]) + 1))
            
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=days, y=df_brook_fil_group[year][mon], marker_color=colors["Collisions"], visible=(j == 0) and (k==0),
                                name='Collisions' if i == 0 else '', showlegend=True if i == 0 else False),
                                row=row_idx, col=column_idx)
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=days, y=df_brook_fore.loc[year, mon][condition], visible=(j == 0),
                                    marker_color=colors[condition], name=condition if i == 0 else '',
                                    showlegend=True if i == 0 else False), row=row_idx, col=column_idx, secondary_y=True)

            fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Collisions", row=row_idx, col=column_idx, secondary_y=False, showgrid=False)
            fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Visibility", row=row_idx, col=column_idx, secondary_y=True, showgrid=False)

fig.update_layout(width=1000, height=1200, coloraxis=dict(colorscale='Bluered_r'), showlegend=True)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label=condition, method="update", args=[{"visible": [((j == i*2) or (j == i*2+1)) for      j in range(
                    len(forecast)*2)]}, {"title": "Normalized Collision Count by Hour for " + condition}])
                for i, condition in enumerate(forecast)

            ]),
            x=0.2, y=1.1, xanchor="left", yanchor="top"
        ),

        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label=str(year), method="update", args=[{"visible": [((j == i*2) or (j == i*2+1)) for j in range(
                    len(years)*2)]}, {"title": "Normalized Collision Count by Hour for " + str(years)}])
                for i, year in enumerate(years)
                
            ]),
            x=0.05, y=1.1, xanchor="left", yanchor="top"
        )
    ],
    title_text="Normalized Collision Count by Hour for " + str(years[0]),
    title_x=0.5
)

fig.show()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: when you have two dropdown lists that both modify the data, plotly can only handle one at a time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470772/plotly-express-multiple-dropdown-menus-in-python))– this means that when you make a selection from one dropdown, plotly won't know what the selection for the other dropdown is because they're independent. to achieve what you want, you probably need a dash based solution because callbacks are supported. let me know if you'd be interested, and i can provide an example

Comment: Hello @DerekO, thanks for the explanation, I tought that I could do it with the double drop down menu, as they have it in the webpage. I'd love to have an example, I'll look now at the stackover post you provided! Thanks!
I don´t know if Dash can achive it, but the idea is to save it as an html so I can upload it to github pages. Does it have the option ?

Comment: can you include your dataframes as formatted text instead of screenshots? this will make it much easier for people to reproduce your figures. you can copy and paste the output from `df_brook_fil_group.head(10).to_dict()` and `df_brook_fore.head(10).to_dict()` directly into your question – thank you!

Comment: @DerekO Good point, I just added the data sets into the question, if you think the outputs from df_brook_fil_group.head(10).to_dict() and df_brook_fore.head(10).to_dict() will be usefull I'll put also them :D

Comment: the full data sets are even better :D

Answer (score 1):

After looking through your code, I think using `Dash` would accomplish several things: (1) it would allow for both dropdowns to be responsive at the same time, and (2) by using a callback function, you can select the data that you need to plot in real-time. There shouldn't be any need to plot all of the traces at the beginning, and then figure out which ones should or shouldn't be visible based on the dropdown selection (and as i'm sure you noticed, this gets really complicated and hard to keep track of when you have year, month, and different forecast columns that you want to process).

Below is an example of what you can achieve with Dash and a callback function to handle inputs from both dropdowns:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

df_brook_fil_group = pd.read_csv('colisions.csv')
df_brook_fil_group = df_brook_fil_group.set_index(['Year','Month','Day'])

df_brook_fore = pd.read_csv('forecast.csv')
df_brook_fore = df_brook_fore.set_index(['Year','Month','Day'])

forecast = list(df_brook_fore.columns[1:])

fig = make_subplots(rows=6, cols=2, specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                            [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                             [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                              [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                               [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                                [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                            ])

# condition = "snow"
colors = {"Collisions": "#FFA07A",
          "tempmax": "#FF0000",
          "tempmin": "#00FF00",
          "temp": "#7EC0EE",
          "humidity": "#808080",
          "precip": "#FFC0CB",
          "snow": "#800080",
          "visibility": "#FFA500",
          }

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="year-dropdown",
                    options=[2014, 2015],
                    value=2014,
                    placeholder="Select year",
                    style={"display": "inline-block", "width": "180px"},
                ),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="forecast-dropdown",
                    options=forecast,
                    value="tempmin",
                    placeholder="Select your forecast column",
                    style={"display": "inline-block", "width": "180px"},
                ),
            ],
            style={"padding": "80px"},
        ),
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id='scatter-bar-chart')
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-bar-chart', 'figure'),
    Input('year-dropdown', 'value'),
    Input('forecast-dropdown', 'value'),
)
def update_output(year, forecast):

    df_brook_fil_group_subset = df_brook_fil_group.loc[year,:,:]
    df_brook_fore_subset = df_brook_fore.loc[year,:,:]
    months = list(range(1,13))

    ## create subplots based on how many months there are
    fig = make_subplots(rows=6, cols=2, specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                            [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                             [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                              [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                               [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                                [{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}],
                                            ])
    
    row, col = 1, 1

    for i, mon in enumerate(months):
        df_brook_fil_group_month = df_brook_fil_group_subset.loc[mon,:] 
        df_brook_fore_month = df_brook_fore_subset.loc[mon,:]

        df_brook_fil_group_days = df_brook_fil_group_month.index.get_level_values('Day')
        df_brook_fore_month_days = df_brook_fore_month.index.get_level_values('Day')

        ## use legendgroups to ensure entries only show up once
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_brook_fil_group_days, y=df_brook_fil_group_month['COLLISION_ID'], 
                                marker_color=colors["Collisions"],
                                showlegend=True if i == 0 else False,
                                name='Collisions', legendgroup='Collisions'),
                                row=row, col=col)
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_brook_fore_month_days, y=df_brook_fore_month[forecast],
                                marker_color=colors[forecast], name=forecast if i == 0 else '',
                                showlegend=True if i == 0 else False,
                                legendgroup=forecast), 
                                row=row, col=col, secondary_y=True)

        fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Collisions", row=row, col=col, secondary_y=False, showgrid=False)
        fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Visibility", row=row, col=col, secondary_y=True, showgrid=False)
        fig.update_layout(
            width=1000, height=1200, 
            coloraxis=dict(colorscale='Bluered_r'), showlegend=True,
            title_text="Normalized Collision Count by Hour for " + str(year),
            title_x=0.5
        )
        
        # iterate through (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2), ... to place the bar + scatter traces
        if i % 2 == 0:
            col += 1
        else:
            row += 1
            if col == 1:
                col = 2
            if col == 2:
                col = 1
        
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The dash app is responsive to both dropdowns for year and forecast type:

[image]

Note: due to the file size, I couldn't show all 6 rows of the app

Comment: did this end up helping?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply, I had a busy cuple of weeks! 
Yes it helped! Though, it is exactly what I wanted to do, I cannot add it to a github pages, which is also one of the goals, I will have to try it in a couple of days!